# Modification to the 'excessive self-promotion' moderator private message

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center, moderator-messages, moderator-templates

The boilerplate text for the '*excessive self-promotion*' moderator contact form includes a direct quote from the [help center](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/behavior):

> Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and
>   tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant
>   answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or
>   website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your
>   answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of
>   your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons.
>   Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team
>   for details. **We also offer free community promotion ads for open source projects and non-profit organizations.**

The sentence written in bold is not included in the actual message sent to users but is written in the help center.

I think this sentence should be included, it is important because the majority of SE sites do not have advertising and many have free community ads.

The following has no relevance to the majority of sites and should be reworded or removed on sites where it has no relevance.

> Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the "excessive self-promotion" mod message template was changed at some point. It now points to the [`/help/promotion`](/help/promotion) page, and the quoted text in the template only includes this portion:

> The community here tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (**but not all**) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.

As such, I'm marking this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).